# How to get the information of When was the last time the Self-Hosted Integration runtime Key is registered?

Tags: azure-data-factory

In Azure Data Factory, I want to know like when was the last Self-Hosted Integration Runtime Key is Registered. I want to know it for periodic renewal of the key. e.g. If I have to renew the Key in the SHIR for every six months. Is there any way in ADF that I can retrieve this information of Key registration?

Comment: We can not find the time when the last Self-Hosted Integration Runtime Key is Registered. One self-hosted integration only support 4 nodes, it means that the key only can be registered 4 times. If you want to renew the Key in the SHIR for every six months, you need uninstall and re-install the integration in your on-premise computer and register the new key. In one word, there isn't a way in ADF that you can retrieve this information of Key.

Comment: Thank you Leon. Is there any workaround possible.

Comment: Hi  @Yogesh Kulkarni, you're welcome. I shared some ideas for you and hope it's helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can not find the time when the last Self-Hosted Integration Runtime Key is Registered. One self-hosted integration only support 4 nodes, it means that the key only can be registered 4 times.

If you want to renew the Key in the SHIR for every six months, you need uninstall and re-install the integration in your on-premise computer and register the new key. In one word, there isn't a way in ADF that you can retrieve this information of Key.

I have an idea that you can get the closest key registered time:
**Microsoft Integration Runtime Manager-->Diagnostic-->view log:**
[image]

Select the earliest logs and find the time:
[image]

As we know, the logs record all the operations, I think it can be useful.

Comment: Thank you Leon. But not sure if these logs will be available for a six months period or more than that.

Comment: @YogeshKulkarni Please check that. For me, I register it less than 6 month.

Comment: @YogeshKulkarni hope you're doing well. Did you get any progresses? If my answer is helpful for you, hope you can accept it as answer. This can be beneficial to other community members. Thank you.

Comment: Thank you Leon. We can consider this as workaround as ADF itself is not providing this feature.